# Infront end of magento 1.9 404 error pagenot found occuring but i added product in category

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have added product in the catogery and in the Em menumanager and i have used the url key  but i am geting 404 page not found error please  help me solve the problem i hav reindexed the index manegement and cleaned cache but what s problem i didn't understand

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have updated the images of question i have asked please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you did below things:

1) Enable Product

2) In inventory set stock to IN STOCK

3) Add .html after url key of product {site_url}/{product_url_key}.html

Comment: i have added .html but even page not found error404 occuring in front end